# Single method which can return the value of a column in a datarow and automatically handle the possibility of the column value to be null

Tags: c#, generics

Can anyone suggest a single method which can return the value of a column in a datarow and automatically handle the possibility of the column value to be null. Essentially I was trying to come up with a generic solution taking advantage of the DataRow extension methods to handle DBNull values. My solution till now has been:

```
public static Nullable<T> SafeRead<T>(DataRow row, string fieldName) where T : struct
{
    if (row.HasColumn(fieldName))
    {
        return row.Field<Nullable<T>>(fieldName) ?? default(Nullable<T>);
    }
    else
        return default(Nullable<T>);
}

public static T SafeRead<T>(DataRow row, string fieldName) where T : class
{
    if (row.HasColumn(fieldName))
    {
        return row.Field<T>(fieldName) ?? default(T);
    }
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

But this obviously complains about method ambiguity since C# does not allow method overloading based on parameter contraints

Comment: Is it out of discussion to give 2 different names ?

Comment: It will be my last resort. But just wanted to explore the possibility of designing a single method which can handle the requisite dynamics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you the value back from the datarow, or the default for the type if the value is DBNull.Value. If the field is not defined it will throw an ArgumentException.

```
using System;
using System.Data;

public static class DataAccess
{
    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(DataRow row, string fieldName)
    {
        if (!row.Table.Columns.Contains(fieldName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("The given DataRow does not contain a field with the name \"{0}\".", fieldName));
        }
        else if (row[fieldName].Equals(DBNull.Value))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        return row.Field<T>(fieldName);
    }
}
```

And here are a few simple tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetValueOrDefault_ValueType_Test()
{
    const string FieldName = "Column";
    const int Expected = 5;

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add(FieldName, typeof(int));

    DataRow row = dataTable.Rows.Add(Expected);

    int actual = DataAccess.GetValueOrDefault<int>(row, FieldName);
    Assert.AreEqual(Expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetValueOrDefault_ValueType_DBNull_Test()
{
    const string FieldName = "Column";

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add(FieldName, typeof(int));

    DataRow row = dataTable.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);

    int actual = DataAccess.GetValueOrDefault<int>(row, FieldName);
    Assert.AreEqual(default(int), actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetValueOrDefault_ReferenceType_Test()
{
    const string FieldName = "Column";
    object expected = new object();

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add(FieldName, typeof(object));

    DataRow row = dataTable.Rows.Add(expected);

    object actual = DataAccess.GetValueOrDefault<object>(row, FieldName);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void GetValueOrDefault_ReferenceType_DBNull_Test()
{
    const string FieldName = "Column";

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add(FieldName, typeof(object));

    DataRow row = dataTable.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);

    object actual = DataAccess.GetValueOrDefault<object>(row, FieldName);
    Assert.AreEqual(default(object), actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always make your own bastardised implementation of Nullable - and return that from your function.

```
public class SafeValue<T>
{
    public T Value {get; set;}
    public bool HasValue
    {
        get
        {
            if(typeof(T).IsClass)
                return Value != null;
            else return true;
        }
    }
}
```

So, replace both with something like:

```
public static SafeValue<T> SafeRead<T>(DataRow row, string fieldName)
{
    if (row.HasColumn(fieldName))
    {
        return new SafeValue<T>{ Value = row.Field<T>(fieldName)};
    }
    else
        return new SafeValue<T>();
}
```

And usage:

```
var val = SafeRead(row, "wah");

if(val.HasValue)
    //DoStuff();
```

Comment: I am not completely sure I understand your solution. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Dave: if T is null (also when T is struct) you should raise an exception on Value{get}, and return false on HasValue.

Comment: Instead of returning Nullable<T> from your function - always return a SafeValue<T> (regardless of struct or not)

Comment: Sorry - my understanding of this question was to have a 'unified' way of reading in values.

Comment: The default value of a struct is whatever the default values of the properties of the struct are - so I don't think you need to test for that...

Comment: @Dave the goal of `Nullable<T>` is to hold null value also for struct. If your class (that basically mimics `Nullable<T>` but allowing `T` being a class) doesn't support that, isn't useful for the purpose of this question. e.g. with your code, if T is int and you call SafeRead on a DBNull record --> it returns 0 instead of null...

Comment: @Dave I agree with digEmAll. But thanks for the code anyway. Might come in handy later. I finally went with the approach by Seth. Lets see if I run into any further issues.